# Writing file to a dynamic path on the server in Django

Tags: python, django, io

I've been looking at a lot of similar questions, both on Google and StackOverflow, but there doesn't seem to be a satisfactory solution that works for me.

My situation is this -

I am using [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) following the steps [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html).

The location where I want to save my files is dynamic and it depends on the `username` and the `session_key`.

This is the function to write the file -

```
def handle_uploaded_file(file, session_key, username):
    folder_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\\Source\\' + username + '\\session_id_' + session_key
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.makedirs(folder_path)
    save_path = folder_path + '\\Source Files'
    with open(save_path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

I tried to upload a file named "normal.csv", but instead I got a file named "Source Files" without an extension inside the directory.

When I changed the path inside the `open()` function to

```
with open(save_path+file.name, 'wb+') as destination
```

I got a file named 'Source Filesnormal.csv'.

I then tried to change the `save_path` to `folder_path + '\\Source Files\\'`, and passed in `save_path+file.name` to `open()`, but then it said `No such file or directory`.

I am very confused as to how to get into that folder location and write the file.

I can't use `MEDIA_URL` here because it depends on the `username` and `session_key`.

Comment: use `os.path.join` to obtain your destination path. string concatenation is not a good way for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give the uploaded file name to the destination path.

It should be something like that:

```
save_path = os.path.join(folder_path, 'Source Files', file.name)
```

which will you give you a path like this:

> ...\Source Files\your_uploaded_file_name

But, keep in mind that you need to check the existence of directories within this path. So, `os.path.exists` check for *'Source Files'* would be good.

```
source_files_path = os.path.join(folder_path, 'Source Files')

if not os.path.exists(source_files_path):
    os.mkdirs(source_files_path)

save_path = os.path.join(source_files_path, file.name)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. How stupid of me. I had completely forgotten to check for the nested directory.

Comment: you know, it happens. glad it helped.